# Thymeleaf 3 with Spring Boot 2, unable to process template

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mocking, mockito, thymeleaf

Before reading, please note that I am new to Thymeleaf, Spring, and Mockito. So I'm expecting that there is some amateur mistake that I'm making.

I am writing code to send emails using thymeleaf HTML templates. I have been looking at different tutorials online and trying to set everything up. I think that my setup is fine, however when I write a test to check that the template is being processed, I get back "null" instead of some form of string.

I have placed a template file in both: src/main/resources/templates and src/test/resources/templates

The file name is email.html

The following is my code to configure the template engine and resolver.

```
    @Configuration
    public class SpringMailConfig{
...
    @Bean
        public SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine(){
            SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
            templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
            templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(emailMessageSource());
            return templateEngine;
        }

        @Bean
        public SpringResourceTemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
            SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
            templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
            templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
            templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
            templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            return templateResolver;
        }
...
    }
```

This is the class in which I want to process the template, I'm only showing what I think is important for this question.

```
@Component
public class EmailServiceHelper {

    @Autowired
    public SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine;

   private  Context prepareContext(Locale locale, Map<String, Object> contextMap){
        final Context context = new Context(locale);
        context.setVariables(contextMap);
        return context;
    }

    //returns as a string the template with the custom values inserted
    private String returnHtmlContent(String templatePath, Locale locale, Map<String,Object> map){
        Context ctx = prepareContext(locale, map);
        return springTemplateEngine.process(templatePath, ctx);
    }

}
```

And this is the test class (part of it) in which I get the error, that springTemplateEngine.process(templatePath, ctx) is returning null.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class )
public class EmailServiceHelperTest {
@Mock
    SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine;

    @Mock
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver springResourceTemplateResolver;
@InjectMocks
EmailServiceHelper helper;

   @Before
    public void setup(){

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        helper = new EmailServiceHelper();
        helper.springTemplateEngine = springTemplateEngine;
    helper.springTemplateEngine.setTemplateResolver(springResourceTemplateResolver);
    }

@Test
    public void testTemplateMessageHasContent(){
        try {
            Locale locale = new Locale("en");
            Map<String, Object> contextMap = new HashMap<>();
            contextMap.put("name", "Test name");
            MimeMessage message = helper.prepareMimeMessage(mail, mailSender, contextMap, "email", locale);
            assertNotNull(message.getContent());
        }catch (MessagingException | IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail("Testing if template message has content failed!");
        }
    }
}
```

This is what my email template looks like.

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>TEMPLATE</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:text="${name}">Hello, Static Person!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please post your pom.xml ?

Comment: In which folder is your email template saved?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. As suspected it was a rookie mistake on my part. Since I was mocking the template engine, I had to to create methods in my test which process the template. Then I did:

```
when(mockObject.processTemplate()).thenReturn(localProcessTemplateMethod();
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the solution, i have exactly the same problem as yours.